# Codeigniter uri language identifier and form_validation not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, internationalization, validation

I have an issue working with codeigniter uri language identifier and form_validation.

The problem is form_validation stops working when I set $config['lang_ignore'] to FALSE.
I have tested in a clean codeigniter installation and setup uri language identifier as said in codeigniter's wiki.

Here's my controller application/controllers/form_validation_test.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Form_validation_test extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{   
    $this->load->view('form_validation_test_view');
}



//Get Ajax POST:
public function getPost()
{
    $result = FALSE;
    $data = NULL;

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user','User','required');

    $result = $this->form_validation->run();

    $response = array(
        'result' => $result
    );

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($response));
}
}
```

View application/views/form_validation_view.php:

```
<script src="http://ci_test.localhost/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ci_test.localhost/js/ci_test.js"></script>

<form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="http://ci_test.localhost/form_validation_test/getPost">
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="">
</form>

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">

<div id="result"></div>
```

and Javascript file js/ci_test.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function(){

    var postData    = jQuery('#formulario').serialize();
    var targetUrl   = jQuery('#formulario').attr('action');     

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:        targetUrl,
        data:       postData,
        type:       'post',
        dataType:   'json', 

        success:    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            res = data.result ? 'TRUE':'FALSE';
            jQuery('#result').html(res);

        }

    });
});
});
```

So as you can see I send post through ajax request, just get the result and place it in div. If you set 'lang_ignore' to TRUE it works, but not if you set it to FALSE.

Another behavior I have observed is that when everythig works fine, you see the POST request in firebug but when using lang_ignore as FALSE you can see the POST request and a GET request that remains loading. I have no idea about why this happens but maybe can help someone find the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

If you set lang_ignore parameter to FALSE, the constructor in application/core/MY_lang.php file does one redirection and (correct me if I'm wrong) you lose the POST.

So including language segment goes straight in one single request.

```
http://ci_test.localhost/en/form_validation_test/getPost
```

It worked for me, hope can help someone